Accessing columns of a numpy ndarray in a vectorized manner
I have a list of lists of indices like so:
outer_list = [[0], [1, 2], [1, 2], [3, 5], [4], [3, 5]]

Each inner list contains the index number of itself within the outer list.
I also have a numpy array with values val_mat. As an example with two rows:
val_mat = np.arange(2*6).reshape(2, 6)

I want to get the row-wise group mean of each index group and store this in a mean-values matrix. In this example, I want (in each row), the element at index 0 to have its value, the elements at index 1 and 2 to have the row-mean of the values at index 1 and 2, and the elements at indices 3 and 5 to have the mean of elements 3 and 5, etc.
At the moment, I am using:
mean_vals = np.vstack([np.nanmean(val_mat[:, inner_list], axis=1) for inner_list in outer_list]).T

However, the outer list is very large (500,000 inner lists) and it takes around 2 minutes for all the mean values to be produced in a 10k x 500k matrix.
Is there a way to do this in a vectorized manner where I don't need to iterate through the outer list?

Are you saying you are creating a 10k x 500k numpy array? Is the dtype np.float64 or something else?

Yeah the mean_vals matrix and val_mat matrix have the same dimensions (10k x 500k). It's dtype np.float32

So the inner_list can be any length, 1, 2, or more?  That will make 'vectorizing' hard.

(10e3500e3 float32)(32 bits/1 float32)*(1 Gigabyte/8e9 bits) = 20 Gigabytes. Do you have enough memory to store a 20-Gigabyte array in RAM?

If you had numpy array instead of list of lists it could be optimized (as hpalj suggested in his answer). You could create np.full((n_rows, max_n_indices), np.nan), fill with values from outer_list, then perform np.nanmean

So your result is
In [93]: mean_vals
Out[93]: 
array([[ 0. ,  1.5,  1.5,  4. ,  4. ,  4. ],
       [ 6. ,  7.5,  7.5, 10. , 10. , 10. ]])

If I change outer_list so all inner lists have the same length:
In [94]: outer_list = [[0,0], [1, 2], [1, 2], [3, 5], [4,4], [3, 5]]

I get the same mean values without the list comprehension:
In [95]: np.mean(val_mat[:, outer_list], axis=2)
Out[95]: 
array([[ 0. ,  1.5,  1.5,  4. ,  4. ,  4. ],
       [ 6. ,  7.5,  7.5, 10. , 10. , 10. ]])

In [96]: val_mat[:, outer_list]
Out[96]: 
array([[[ 0,  0],
        [ 1,  2],
        [ 1,  2],
        [ 3,  5],
        [ 4,  4],
        [ 3,  5]],

       [[ 6,  6],
        [ 7,  8],
        [ 7,  8],
        [ 9, 11],
        [10, 10],
        [ 9, 11]]])

Contrast that with your original list:
In [99]: [val_mat[:, inner_list] for inner_list in outer_list]
Out[99]: 
[array([[0],
        [6]]),
 array([[1, 2],
        [7, 8]]),
 array([[1, 2],
        [7, 8]]),
 array([[ 3,  5],
        [ 9, 11]]),
 array([[ 4],
        [10]]),
 array([[ 3,  5],
        [ 9, 11]])]

Other than making the inner lists consistent in shape, I don't have a 'vectorizing' suggestion for improving speed.

I've managed to speed up the computation a little bit using numba and making custom mean() function (to not use any memory allocation):
import numba
import numpy as np

@numba.njit
def my_mean(m, subl, out):
    for row in range(m.shape[0]):
        acc = 0
        for i in subl:
            acc += m[row, i]
        out[row] = acc / len(subl)


def calculate(mat, lst):
    out = np.empty(shape=(len(lst), mat.shape[0]), dtype="float32")
    for i, subl in enumerate(lst):
        my_mean(mat, subl, out[i])
    return out.T


Benchmark using (100x500k matrix):
from random import randint, sample
from timeit import timeit

import numba
import numpy as np


def calculate_original(mat, lst):
    return np.vstack(
        [np.mean(val_mat[:, inner_list], axis=1) for inner_list in outer_list]
    ).T


@numba.njit
def my_mean(m, subl, out):
    for row in range(m.shape[0]):
        acc = 0
        for i in subl:
            acc += m[row, i]
        out[row] = acc / len(subl)


def calculate(mat, lst):
    out = np.empty(shape=(len(lst), mat.shape[0]), dtype="float32")
    for i, subl in enumerate(lst):
        my_mean(mat, subl, out[i])
    return out.T


outer_list = [[0], [1, 2], [1, 2], [3, 5], [4], [3, 5]]
val_mat = np.array(np.arange(2 * 6).reshape(2, 6))

out1 = calculate(val_mat, outer_list)
out2 = calculate_original(val_mat, outer_list)
assert np.allclose(out1, out2)


N = 500_000
M = 100
outer_list = [sorted(sample(range(N), k=randint(1, 5))) for i in range(N)]
val_mat = np.array(np.arange(M * N).reshape(M, N))

out1 = calculate(val_mat, outer_list)
out2 = calculate_original(val_mat, outer_list)

assert np.allclose(out1, out2)

t1 = timeit("calculate_original(val_mat, outer_list)", globals=globals(), number=1)
t2 = timeit("calculate(val_mat, outer_list)", globals=globals(), number=1)

print("original =", t1)
print("numba    =", t2)

Prints on my machine:
original = 5.369414679007605
numba    = 3.000408222898841

So speed-up ~80%
